# How to get file from form wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a page with a form.

```
<form method='post'>
<input type='file' name='file_image'>
<input type='submit' value='send'>
</form>
```

When they submit, how do I get the image uploaded into the "wp-content/uploads/" folder.

And if you can, how can I resize the image as it is being uploaded?

Please, just show me the code with comments and if there is more than one way of doing it, I would be happy to know. Thank you.

Comment: Are you asking how to upload the image, or are you asking how to grab a file already uploaded.  If the latter, we'll need to know how it was uploaded in the first place.

Comment: How to upload the image when the submit button is pressed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    if ( ! function_exists( 'wp_handle_upload' ) ) require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
    $uploadedfile = $_FILES['file'];
    $upload_overrides = array( 'test_form' => false );
    $movefile = wp_handle_upload( $uploadedfile, $upload_overrides );
    if ( $movefile ) {
        echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
        var_dump( $movefile);
    } else {
        echo "Possible file upload attack!\n";
    }
```

To know about that please check this link below:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_handle_upload

Comment: Thank you for this answer and the link. It answers my question simply.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you everyone for your contribution. It helped.
Just to summarise.
There is 2 ways to do this.

The first way is using a wordpress function

```
//Check if function exist
if (!function_exists('wp_handle_upload')) {
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
}

//Store file in variable
$uploaded_file = $_FILES['file_image'];

//Overrides
upload_overrides = array('test_form' => false);

//Store upload in variable
$movefile = wp_handle_upload($uploaded_file,$upload_overrides);

//Check if upload was successful
if ($movefile) {
echo "File is valid and was successfully uploaded";
var_dump($movefile); //show details
} else {
echo "Possible file upload attack";
}
```

The second way is using a php function

```
//Check if file exist
if (file_exists("full_path/uploads" . $_FILES["file_image"]["name"])) {
echo $_FILES["file_image"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
} 
else {
//Store file in variable
$uploadedfile = "full_path/uploads".$_FILES["file_image"]["name"];
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file_image"]["tmp_name"], $uploadedfile);
echo "Stored in: " . $uploadedfile;
}
```

The html

```
<form method='post'>
<input type='file' name='file_image'>
<input type='submit' value='send'>
</form>
```

**The first way** automatically creates the folders like "uploads/2014/09/file_name"

**The second way** you have to create the folders manually

*Working Code*

Answer (score 0):

Your file is in `$_FILES["file_image"]`, as it has that name in your form.

You can copy your file using  [move_uploaded_file](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.move-uploaded-file.php)

[Here](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Scripting/PHP/Q_21330036.html) you have an example of moving and resizing an uploaded image.

Answer (score 0):

First Replace 
this

```
<form method='post'>
```

to

```
<form method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
```

And you will get file name in  `$_FILES['file_image']['name']` after form submit,

Then use ,`move_uploaded_file(file,newloc)`
[Check this.](http://www.developphp.com/page.php?id=449)

Answer (score 0):

Little research and efforts will move you to the right direction. Take a look on this link that describe you in details to upload images from font end.

http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/allow-users-to-submit-images-to-your-wordpress-site--wp-22601

Let the WordPress do his work for manage media for storing and re-sizing, WordPress Media Upload script one of the most powerful and smart technique to re-sizing image.

Comment: Thank you for your comment but I did do research. The link you sent, I have already seen before I asked. The link is a backend solution then frontend but your contribution is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

File upload form

```
<form method='post' action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type='file' name='file_image'>
    <input type='submit' value='send'>
</form>
```

Your Upload file:

```
if (file_exists("/wp-content/upload/" . $_FILES["file_image"]["name"])) {
    echo $_FILES["file_image"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
} else {
    $uploadedfile = "/wp-content/upload/".$_FILES["file_image"]["name"];
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file_image"]["tmp_name"], $uploadedfile);
    echo "Stored in: " . $uploadedfile;
}
```

The resizing bit I strongly recommend to do yourself. There are several great tutorials:

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/image-resizing-made-easy-with-php--net-10362

http://www.white-hat-web-design.co.uk/blog/resizing-images-with-php/

However, if you are writing a plugin for a wordpress these things are already avaliable to you:

http://www.inkthemes.com/code-to-integrate-wordpress-media-uploader-in-plugintheme/06/

Comment: Thank you for this answer and the links.
This is another way I can upload the image instead of using wp_handle_upload.
I appreciate it.